# customizing javafx 3d box or rotating stackpane

Tags: javafx, 3d, javafx-3d

My goal is a game played with dice. I am using javafx.

**First question:** Is there an easy way to customize the 3d box in javafx. It doesn't matter to me, if I have to add an image to every side of the die or if I use just one image which wraps around the box.  (After lots of research I didn't find anything about it.)

In the code below I created a stackpane, which is a 3d cube. It is build from 6 Rectangles, each of the is filled with one side of a die (1 to 6). If I rotate the stackpane by 180 degrees, the Rectangle which should be in the foreground is in the background and the one which was before in front is visible again.

**Second question:**  How to fix this?

Or is there a better way to realize that? First I was thinking about using TriangleMesh, but it seemd to be as complicated as my version.

```
@FXML
private StackPane stack;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
...
//other code


for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++){   
            Rectangle rt = getRectangle(i);
            rt.setSmooth(true);
            stack.getChildren().add(rt);
            switch(i) {
                case 1:
                    rt.setTranslateZ(100);                        
                    break;
                case 2:
                    rt.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(270, 50,50,0,Rotate.X_AXIS));
                    rt.setTranslateZ(100*0.5);
                    rt.setHeight(100);
                    rt.setTranslateY(100*0.5);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    rt.setTranslateZ(100*0.5);
                    rt.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(90, 50, 50, 0, Rotate.Y_AXIS));
                    rt.setWidth(100);
                    rt.setTranslateX(-(100*0.5-1));
                    break;
                case 4:
                    rt.setTranslateZ(100*0.5);
                    rt.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(90,50,50,0,Rotate.Y_AXIS));
                    rt.setWidth(100);
                    rt.setTranslateX(100*0.5);
                    break;
                case 5:    
                    rt.setTranslateZ(100*0.5);
                    rt.setTranslateY(-(100*0.5));
                    rt.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(270,50,50,0, Rotate.X_AXIS));
                    rt.setHeight(100);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    rt.setTranslateZ(0);
                    break;
            }      

private Rectangle getRectangle(int number){
    Rectangle rt = new Rectangle(100, 100);
    rt.setFill(new ImagePattern(loadImage(number)));
    return rt;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with `Box`, as you may have already noticed, is that if you apply an image as diffuse map, it will be applied equally to all its 6 faces.

If you have a look at [FXyz](https://github.com/Birdasaur/FXyz) project, there's an implementation of a similar 3D shape, `CuboidMesh`.

Having full access to its 'TriangleMesh` it's easy to customize the way the texture is mapped to a diffuse image. In this case, the way its implemented is by using the net of the cube:

[image: Cube net]

So now you just need to provide your own net. For instance, this one:

[image: Dice net]

from [here](http://villemin.gerard.free.fr/Wwwgvmm/Probabil/DesJeu_fichiers/image014.jpg)

Just rotate it 180º and crop it to its border, and with this short code you will have your dice:

```
CuboidMesh cuboid = new CuboidMesh(10f,10f,10f);
cuboid.setTextureModeImage(getClass().getResource("rotated_image014.jpg").toExternalForm());
```

[image: Dice]