# How to add text to each face of a box [JavaFX]

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-3d

I create a box which I can rotate and what will do ~some action~ when clicked. The problem I'm having is display text on all the faces of this box, for example;
1 on the front, 2 on the top, 3 on the back, 4 on the bottom, 5 on the left and 6 on the right.

I understand that StackPane can be used to overlay a text box on-top of the cube but I don't think that'd really help in this scenario.
Since box is essentially a pre-constructed TriangleMesh, is this possible to do?
As far as seen, box doesn't have any in-built functionality to do this.

```
static double mousePosX;
static double mousePosY;
static double mouseOldX;
static double mouseOldY;
public static Scene testScene(Stage stage) {


    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, stage.getWidth(), stage.getHeight(), true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
    scene.setFill(Paint.valueOf("Blue"));

    PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);
    camera.setNearClip(0.1);
    camera.setFarClip(10000.0);
    camera.setTranslateZ(-10);
    scene.setCamera(camera);

    Box box = new Box(1,1,1);
    box.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
        System.out.println("Test");
    });

    Rotate rotateX = new Rotate(10, 0, 0, 0, Rotate.X_AXIS);
    Rotate rotateY = new Rotate(5, 0, 0, 0, Rotate.Y_AXIS);
    box.getTransforms().addAll(rotateX, rotateY);

    scene.setOnMousePressed(me -> {
        mouseOldX = me.getSceneX();
        mouseOldY = me.getSceneY();
    });
    scene.setOnMouseDragged(me -> {
        mousePosX = me.getSceneX();
        mousePosY = me.getSceneY();
        rotateX.setAngle(rotateX.getAngle() - (mousePosY - mouseOldY));
        rotateY.setAngle(rotateY.getAngle() + (mousePosX - mouseOldX));
        mouseOldX = mousePosX;
        mouseOldY = mousePosY;
    });

    root.getChildren().add(box);

    return scene;
}
```

This is the code I've got so far and any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is based in the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274295/customizing-javafx-3d-box-or-rotating-stackpane/31274989#31274989), where the `CuboidMesh` from the FXyz [library](https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz) is used.

The main idea is to use an image as texture for the cube. The built-in JavaFX `Box` will apply this image to each of the 6 faces, so if we want to have different text in each face, we have to use the `CuboidMesh`, that makes use of the net image:

[image: net for cube]

The cube can be generated as:

```
CuboidMesh cuboid = new CuboidMesh(100f, 100f, 100f);
cuboid.setTextureModeImage(getClass().getResource("net.png").toExternalForm());
```

The idea now is to write the text in each of the 6 faces and save the texture image that will be used later on.

This method will generate this net image:

```
private Image generateNet(String face1, String face2, String face3, String face4, String face5, String face6) {

    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    Label label1 = new Label(face1);
    label1.setRotate(90);
    GridPane.setHalignment(label1, HPos.CENTER);

    Label label2 = new Label(face2);
    GridPane.setHalignment(label2, HPos.CENTER);

    Label label3 = new Label(face3);
    GridPane.setHalignment(label3, HPos.CENTER);

    Label label4 = new Label(face4);
    GridPane.setHalignment(label4, HPos.CENTER);

    Label label5 = new Label(face5);
    GridPane.setHalignment(label5, HPos.CENTER);

    Label label6 = new Label(face6);
    label6.setRotate(90);
    GridPane.setHalignment(label6, HPos.CENTER);

    grid.add(label1, 1, 0);
    grid.add(label2, 0, 1);
    grid.add(label3, 1, 1);
    grid.add(label4, 2, 1);
    grid.add(label5, 3, 1);
    grid.add(label6, 1, 2);

    grid.setGridLinesVisible(true);

    ColumnConstraints col1 = new ColumnConstraints();
    col1.setPercentWidth(25);
    ColumnConstraints col2 = new ColumnConstraints();
    col2.setPercentWidth(25);
    ColumnConstraints col3 = new ColumnConstraints();
    col3.setPercentWidth(25);
    ColumnConstraints col4 = new ColumnConstraints();
    col4.setPercentWidth(25);
    grid.getColumnConstraints().addAll(col1, col2, col3, col4);

    RowConstraints row1 = new RowConstraints();
    row1.setPercentHeight(33.33);
    RowConstraints row2 = new RowConstraints();
    row2.setPercentHeight(33.33);
    RowConstraints row3 = new RowConstraints();
    row3.setPercentHeight(33.33);
    grid.getRowConstraints().addAll(row1, row2, row3);
    grid.setPrefSize(600, 450);

    Scene tmpScene = new Scene(grid);
    tmpScene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());

    return grid.snapshot(null, null);
}
```

where `style.css` contains:

```
.root {
    -fx-background-color: white;
}
.label {
    -fx-font-size: 6em;
}
```

With it, the labels size and font can be adjusted properly.

Now you can generate a net image for any text:

```
Image net = generateNet("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6");
```

[image]

Finally, you can apply this texture to the cuboid:

```
PhongMaterial mat = new PhongMaterial();
mat.setDiffuseMap(net);
cuboid.setMaterial(mat);
```

And you will have your text applied:

[image: cuboid with text]

Comment: What would the import for CuboidMesh be?

Comment: You can find the `CuboidMesh` class [here](https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz/blob/master/FXyz-Core/src/main/java/org/fxyz3d/shapes/primitives/CuboidMesh.java), and the import will be `org.fxyz3d.shapes.primitives.CuboidMesh`.

Comment: If you didn't have a connection to the internet, would this option still be viable?

Comment: Just download the jar and add it to your project?

Comment: Thanks for the help :)