# Showing texts over the face of a Box based on the visible area on zooming in/out

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-3d

I have a sample 3D application (built by taking reference from the Javafx sample 3DViewer) which has a table created by laying out Boxes and Panes: 
[image: (table image)]

The table is centered wrt (0,0,0) coordinates and camera is at -z position initially.

It has the zoom-in/out based on the camera z position from the object.
On zooming in/out the object's boundsInParent increases/decreases i.e. area of the face increases/decreases. So the idea is to put more text when we have more area (always confining within the face) and lesser text or no text when the face area is too less. I am able to to do that using this node hierarchy:

[image: this node hierarchy]

and resizing the Pane (and managing the vBox and number of texts in it) as per Box on each zoom-in/out.

Now the issue is that table boundsInParent is giving incorrect results ([table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7cBE.jpg) showing the boundingBox off at the top) whenever a text is added to the vBox for the first time only. On further zooming-in/out gives correct boundingBox and does not go off.

Below is the UIpane3D class:

```
public class UIPane3D extends Pane
{
VBox textPane;

ArrayList<String> infoTextKeys = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Text> infoTextValues = new ArrayList<>();

Rectangle bgCanvasRect = null;

final double fontSize = 16.0;   

public UIPane3D() {
    setMouseTransparent(true);
    textPane = new VBox(2.0)
}

public void updateContent() {
    textPane.getChildren().clear();
    getChildren().clear();

    for (Text textNode : infoTextValues) {
        textPane.getChildren().add(textNode);
        textPane.autosize();
        if (textPane.getHeight() > getHeight()) {
            textPane.getChildren().remove(textNode);
            textPane.autosize();

            break;
        }
    }

    textPane.setTranslateY(getHeight() / 2 - textPane.getHeight() / 2.0);

    bgCanvasRect = new Rectangle(getWidth(), getHeight());
    bgCanvasRect.setFill(Color.web(Color.BURLYWOOD.toString(), 0.10));
    bgCanvasRect.setVisible(true);

    getChildren().addAll(bgCanvasRect, textPane);
}


public void resetInfoTextMap()
{
    if (infoTextKeys != null || infoTextValues != null) 
    {
        try 
        {
            infoTextKeys.clear();
            infoTextValues.clear();     
        } catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}


public void updateInfoTextMap(String pKey, String pValue)
{
    int index = -1;
    boolean objectFound = false;

    for (String string : infoTextKeys) 
    {
        index++;
        if(string.equals(pKey))
        {
            objectFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(objectFound)
    {
        infoTextValues.get(index).setText(pValue.toUpperCase());
    }
    else
    {
        if (pValue != null) 
        {   
            Text textNode = new Text(pValue.toUpperCase());
            textNode.setFont(Font.font("Consolas", FontWeight.BLACK, FontPosture.REGULAR, fontSize));
            textNode.wrappingWidthProperty().bind(widthProperty());
            textNode.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
            infoTextKeys.add(pKey);
            infoTextValues.add(textNode);
        }
    }
}
```

}

The code which get called at the last after all the manipulations:

```
public void refreshBoundingBox()
{
    if(boundingBox != null)
    {
        root3D.getChildren().remove(boundingBox);
    }

    PhongMaterial blueMaterial = new PhongMaterial();
    blueMaterial.setDiffuseColor(Color.web(Color.CRIMSON.toString(), 0.25));

    Bounds tableBounds = table.getBoundsInParent();
    boundingBox = new Box(tableBounds.getWidth(), tableBounds.getHeight(), tableBounds.getDepth());
    boundingBox.setMaterial(blueMaterial);
    boundingBox.setTranslateX(tableBounds.getMinX() + tableBounds.getWidth()/2.0);
    boundingBox.setTranslateY(tableBounds.getMinY() + tableBounds.getHeight()/2.0);
    boundingBox.setTranslateZ(tableBounds.getMinZ() + tableBounds.getDepth()/2.0);
    boundingBox.setMouseTransparent(true);

    root3D.getChildren().add(boundingBox);
}
```

Two things:

1. The table3D's boundsInParent is not updated properly when texts are added for the first time.
2. What would be the right way of putting texts on 3D nodes? I am having to manipulate a whole lot to bring the texts as required.

Sharing code [here](https://github.com/vedrm/Issues_Javafx/tree/master/BoundingBoxBug).

Comment: Probably it would be best if you share the code, at least something we can use to reproduce your issue?

Comment: @JoséPereda shared code link, main class: JFXApp.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first question, about the "jump" that can be noticed just when after scrolling a new text item is laid out:

[image: moving bounds]

After digging into the [code](https://github.com/vedrm/Issues_Javafx/tree/master/BoundingBoxBug), I noticed that the `UIPane3D` has a `VBox textPane` that contains the different Text nodes. Every time `updateContent` is called, it tries to add a text node, but it checks that the vbox's height is always lower than the pane's height, or else the node will be removed:

```
    for (Text textNode : infoTextValues) {
        textPane.getChildren().add(textNode);
        textPane.autosize();
        if (textPane.getHeight() > getHeight()) {
            textPane.getChildren().remove(textNode);
            textPane.autosize();
            break;
        }
    }
```

While this is basically correct, when you add a node to the scene, you can't get `textPane.getHeight()` immediately, as it hasn't been laid out yet, and you have to wait until the next pulse. This is why the next time you scroll, the height is correct and the bounding box is well placed.

One way to force the layout and get the correct height of the `textNode` is by forcing css and a layout pass:

```
    for (Text textNode : infoTextValues) {
        textPane.getChildren().add(textNode);

        // force css and layout
        textPane.applyCss();
        textPane.layout();

        textPane.autosize();
        if (textPane.getHeight() > getHeight()) {
            textPane.getChildren().remove(textNode);
            textPane.autosize();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Note that:

> This method [`applyCss`] does not normally need to be invoked directly but may be used in conjunction with `Parent.layout()` to size a Node before the next pulse, or if the Scene is not in a Stage.

For the second question, about a different solution to add Text to 3D Shape.

Indeed, placing a (2D) text on top of a 3D shape is quite difficult, and requires complex maths (that are done quite nicely in the project, by the way).

There is an alternative avoiding the use of 2D nodes directly.

Precisely in a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48618329/how-to-add-text-to-each-face-of-a-box-javafx), I "wrote" into an image, that later on I used as the material diffuse map of a 3D shape.

The built-in 3D `Box` places the same image into every face, so that wouldn't work. We can implement a 3D prism, or we can make use of the `CuboidMesh` node from the FXyz3D [library](https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz).

Replacing the `Box` in `UIPaneBoxGroup`:

```
final CuboidMesh contentShape;
UIPane3D displaypane = null;
PhongMaterial shader = new PhongMaterial();
final Color pColor;

public UIPaneBoxGroup(final double pWidth, final double pHeight, final double pDepth, final Color pColor) { 
    contentShape = new CuboidMesh(pWidth, pHeight, pDepth);
    this.pColor = pColor;
    contentShape.setMaterial(shader);
    getChildren().add(contentShape);
    addInfoUIPane();
}
```

and adding the `generateNet` method:

```
private Image generateNet(String string) {

    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    Label label5 = new Label(string);
    label5.setFont(Font.font("Consolas", FontWeight.BLACK, FontPosture.REGULAR, 40));
    GridPane.setHalignment(label5, HPos.CENTER);

    grid.add(label5, 3, 1);

    double w = contentShape.getWidth() * 10; // more resolution
    double h = contentShape.getHeight() * 10;
    double d = contentShape.getDepth() * 10;
    final double W = 2 * d + 2 * w;
    final double H = 2 * d + h;

    ColumnConstraints col1 = new ColumnConstraints();
    col1.setPercentWidth(d * 100 / W);
    ColumnConstraints col2 = new ColumnConstraints();
    col2.setPercentWidth(w * 100 / W);
    ColumnConstraints col3 = new ColumnConstraints();
    col3.setPercentWidth(d * 100 / W);
    ColumnConstraints col4 = new ColumnConstraints();
    col4.setPercentWidth(w * 100 / W);
    grid.getColumnConstraints().addAll(col1, col2, col3, col4);

    RowConstraints row1 = new RowConstraints();
    row1.setPercentHeight(d * 100 / H);
    RowConstraints row2 = new RowConstraints();
    row2.setPercentHeight(h * 100 / H);
    RowConstraints row3 = new RowConstraints();
    row3.setPercentHeight(d * 100 / H);
    grid.getRowConstraints().addAll(row1, row2, row3);
    grid.setPrefSize(W, H);
    grid.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(pColor, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
    new Scene(grid);
    return grid.snapshot(null, null);
}
```

Now all the 2D related code can be removed (including `displaypane`), and after a scrolling event get the image:

```
public void refreshBomUIPane() {        
    Image net = generateNet(displaypane.getText());
    shader.setDiffuseMap(net);
}
```

where in `UIPane3D`:

```
public String getText() {
    return infoTextKeys.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
}
```

I've also removed the bounding box to get this picture:

[image: Just CuboidMeshes]

I haven't played around with the number of text nodes that can be added to the VBox, the font size nor with an strategy to avoid generating images on every scroll: only when the text changes this should be done. So with the current approach is quite slow, but it can be improved notably as there are only three possible images for each box.

Comment: got that, the layout pass before next pulse, thanks.

Comment: For the second question, shading the 3D object with an image (that too different texts at different faces using the FXyz3D library and grid approach) is a good option to show texts and avoid 2D. But later I would like to have those 3D Boxes interactive (having a button etc) for which I chose Panes over them. Not sure whether mixing 2D in 3D is a good design?

Comment: I'm not fond of mixing both 2D and 3D in the same subScene. But it depends on your use case, of course. If you want to add interaction, maybe you can even try 3D (combining pickResult and small mesh animations...), and maybe a 2D panel/popup/overlay (in case you need a TextField or so, that doesn't need to be in the same subScene, see [this](https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz/blob/master/Fxyz-Samples/src/main/java/org/fxyz3d/samples/utilities/FloatingLabels.java)). This [project](https://github.com/jperedadnr/RubikFX) is not the same as yours, but can give you a hint on mesh interactions.